# Reset Chakra UI Editable Input when editing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chakra-ui

I am using the chakra UI Editable component and set '-' as the default value if there is no value available. So, when editing input is visible as below. But I want to remove the '-' when editing.

[image]

Here is my code.

```
<Editable
 defaultValue={rate || '-'}
 submitOnBlur={false}
>
{(props) => (
  <>
    <EditablePreview/>
    <EditableInput
        onBlur={null}
    />
    <EditableControls
        {...props}
        id={no}
    />
  </>
)}
```

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/summer-sound-0wvcr?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Can you add sandbox for this? Or full code. Its easy to fix than

Comment: Here is my sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/summer-sound-0wvcr?file=/src/App.js

Comment: @ShubhamVerma Here is my sandbox: codesandbox.io/s/summer-sound-0wvcr?file=/src/App.js

Comment: You need to handle this via your own controlled component. As soon as you clicked on edit the value will not be there . So you will never get `-` this while editing. Here is small POC i tried: https://codesandbox.io/s/quirky-galileo-v3l4b?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `placeholder` props provided by Chakra UI to achieve what you want.

[Visit documentation to know more](https://chakra-ui.com/docs/components/editable/props)

[Visit Sandbox-->](https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-tree-8j6in0?file=/src/App.js:1014-1413)